# QGIS startup error (symbol lookup error, undefined symbol) after system update

Tags: qgis, linux-mint

I'm using QGIS 2.4.0 on Linux Mint 16 MATE 64-bit. This afternoon I did a normal system update via apt-get update && apt-get upgrade followed by apt-get autoclean && autoremove. But then suddenly my QGIS stopped working. This is the error message I got

```
/usr/bin/qgis.bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZN10QSslSocket16staticMetaObjectE
```

I tried to uninstall (apt-get purge) & reinstall QGIS but still got the same error message

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: Picking up the wrong version of Qt it seems

Comment: Thanks Nathan! If it's the case, how could I point to the right one then?

Comment: what kind of installation have you used? Stand-alone (file .deb) ubuntu official repos or ubuntugis repository?

Comment: I installed from ubuntugis repository I believe

Comment: If you are sure, I agree with Nathan. There is something wrong in the Qt library packages.